# Magento Multi store permanent 301 redirect via .htaccess

Tags: magento, http-status-code-301

We have a multistore website on Magento.

```
Website1.co.uk (main)
Website2.co.uk (running)
Website3.co.uk (new)
```

We want to change `website2.co.uk` to new domain `website3.co.uk` using 301 for a permanent redirect.

How can we do this through .htaccess or any other way without losing the traffic on running a website?

Also, `website3.co.uk` has a new theme. So how will it affect the `website2.co.uk` view?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website2.co.uk [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website2.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website3.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below tutorial link to resolve this issue:

https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains